# Compare objects of child and parent classes in javers

Tags: java, javers

I have two classes:

```
class A {
  @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
  String id;      
  String field;
}
class B extends A {
  @DiffIgnore
  String someOtherField;
}
```

I want to compare instance of class A and instance of class B.
Both instances have the same `id`.

Please tell if that is possible anyhow with Javers.

I've already did research on Internet, tried to use the same or different `@TypeName`, tried as `@ValueObject` and with `@Entity` - nothing helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `@TypeName` and give both classes the same name.
And then JaVers compares objects but only properties declared in the super type.

I wrote the test to show it (Groovy):

```groovy
class CaseWithInheritance extends Specification{
    @TypeName("A")
    class A {
        @Id
        String id
        String field
    }
    @TypeName("A")
    class B extends A {
        @DiffIgnore
        String someOtherField
    }

    def "should compare objects' intersection"(){
      given:
      def a = new A(id:1, field:"aa")
      def b = new B(id:1, field:"bb", someOtherField:"b")
      def javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build()

      when:
      def diff = javers.compare(a, b)

      then:
      diff.changes.size() == 1
      println diff.prettyPrint()
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Diff:
* changes on A/1 :
  - 'field' changed from 'aa' to 'bb'
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I am receiving "wrappedCdo is not an instance of given managedClass" because my class A is treated as class B. That is because org.javers.core.metamodel.type.TypeMapper contains incorrect state like: ``{DuckType{typeName='A', properties=['id','field']}=class package-name.A, DuckType{typeName='A', properties=['id','field','someOtherField']}=class package-name.B, DuckType{typeName='A', properties=[]}=class package-name.B}``. When search is performed ``DuckType{typeName='A', properties=[]}`` is used leading to error.

Comment: so you are committing?

Comment: I will try to create a sample github project this weekend.